# Suspend of the screen problem

Tags: suspend

If I use Win + L key. Then after 10 or 30 minutes. When I try to open the lid of the laptop, it show me black screen. I have reinstalled the version by formatting all the data with ubuntu 23.10. Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: let say I am working on my laptop. And If I took a break for about 30 minutes and lock the screen. Then after 30 mints or an hour the OS crashed and I have to reboot my laptop. So much irritating it is. As I have to open my apps again.

Comment: A black screen after waiting after locking is normal. A black screen after closing the lid of the laptop is also normal. You can disable screen blanking and lid actions in settings

Comment: show black screen for sometime but the screen got freeze and then I have to hard Reboot the system to work.